# Angular 2 Calling function from Component HTML returns empty

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Here is my ts file. When ever I call tempData() method in another or same typescript it will return proper info. But when I call it from HTML file it returns 0 for **this.links.length** and also returns wrong ID for **this.graph**

```
export class EditRelationColsComponent implements OnInit {
  graph: any = new joint.dia.Graph;


constructor(private globalService: GlobalService) {
  }

ngOnInit() {
 }
  tempData(){
    console.log(this.graph);
    console.log(this.links.length);
 }
}
```

HTML

```
<button class="diag" pButton type="button" (click)="tempData()"  class="ui-button-info" label="Save"></button>
```

So when I call function from another JS (After I call the **loadGraph()**), my graph ID is: 307
When I call function from HTMl, my graph ID is: 308. I don't know why it's not looking for proper graph, but instead creating new one?

Answer (score 0):

Too fast close tag "}". Try this.

```
export class EditRelationColsComponent implements OnInit {
  graph: any = new joint.dia.Graph;


  constructor(private globalService: GlobalService) {
  }

 ngOnInit() {
 }
 tempData(){
    console.log(this.graph);
    console.log(this.links.length);
 }
}
```